# Start an android Activity from PhoneGap javaScript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to start an android activity from my phonegap javascript file. I have seen a few post from years ago when DroidGap was still utilized. Does anyone know how to do this with the current updated version of phoneGap? Please do not point me to any posts that refer to the old version of PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is a native plugin.
You can call your native code from within your JavaScript and then stat your activity as usual.
Documentation for plugins (for android) is [located here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html).